# TFS 2010 - how to re-add MS Project, Excel, etc

Tags: ms-project

I installed TFS 2010 (RC) on my servers then installed VS2008 Team Explorer and SPs on my client.  Next, I installed VS2010 Team Explorer (VS Shell).  I've been using it for a few days now and I've been able to right-click/open in Project with no problem.  Today, I am getting:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'.  This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error:  Library not registered.

Two questions:

1. Why is it trying to talk to Outlook when I requested Project?
2. How do I fix my machine?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  Several reboots later I cannot get this to do this anymore.